# Apply ViewModifier to UIViewRepresentable

Tags: swiftui, uiviewrepresentable

I created a UIViewRespresentable for a UITextField. I'd like to apply modifiers:

```
myTextField.font(.headline).keyboardType(keyboardType)
```

This is not working, even if my UIViewRepresentable is simple:

```
class MyTextField: UITextField { ... }

struct MyFieldField: UIViewRepresentable {
    private let field = MyTextField()
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MyTextField { return field }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MyTextField, context: Context) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`UITextField` is a UIKit component, not a SwiftUI component.  It doesn't currently respect `.font()` or any other SwiftUI modifiers.  Furthermore, you [cannot currently create](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/font) a `UIFont` from a SwiftUI `Font`.  So, although you can do `@Environment(\.font) var font: Font` to get the current value, you won't be able to do anything useful with it in UIKit land.

You can:

1. Just set a `UIFont` directly on your `UIViewRepresentable`
2. Use `UIFont.TextStyle`
3. Map between `Font.TextStyle` and `UIFont.TextStyle`

With any of these you will need to explicitly create a variable on your `UIViewRepresentable` to hold that value, and then apply it during `updateUIView(context:)`

```swift
struct MyFieldField: UIViewRepresentable {
  // Your three options
  var myUIFont: UIFont
  var myUITextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle
  var mySwiftUITextStyle: Font.TextStyle // map this onto UIFont.TextStyle
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there was a way MyTextField could get the modifiers and go through them and apply them to the underlying UITextField (mapping them as you point out).